# Adding db2 xa datasource to JBoss 7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, java-11

I am trying to add db2 xa datasource on JBoss.
JBoss 7.1, 
Java 11.

This is part of my `standalone-full-ha.xml`.

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="db2jcc" module="com.ibm">
                    <driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>

            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

The directory structure is, `standalone-modules-com-ibm-main` and I added jar files(db2jcc.jar, db2jcc_license_cu.jar, db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar) and module.xml in.
My module.xml is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="com.ibm" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="db2jcc.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="db2jcc_license_cu.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I tried,
`.\standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full-ha.xml`, but it didn't change at all. It does not display it on `Detected` tab on the console.
The log file shows,

```
  1  INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-1) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
  2   [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) MODCLUSTER000002: Initiating mod_cluster shutdown
  3  INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/Ex    ampleDS]
  4  INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
  5 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:    8443
  6  INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
  7  INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000082: Stopping the RpcDispatcher for cha    nnel ejb
  8  INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-8) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
  9  INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
 10  INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-8) ISPN000082: Stopping the RpcDispatcher for cha    nnel ejb
 11  INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000082: Stopping the RpcDispatcher for cha    nnel ejb
 12  INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
 13  INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000082: Stopping the RpcDispatcher for cha    nnel ejb
 14  INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
 15  INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.4.18.Final-redhat-2 stopping
 16  INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
 17  INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment xxxxx.war (runtime-name: xxxxx.war) in 836ms
 18  INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0050: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) stopped in 844ms
 19  INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.0.Final-redhat-1
 20  FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0239: Aborting with exit code 1
 21  INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.0.Final-redhat-1
 22 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0239: Aborting with exit code 1
```

Can anyone point out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check the official documenentation for this:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuration_guide/datasource_management#example_ibm_db2_xa_datasource
Secondly, Java 11 has been tested and supported ONLY with EAP 7.2! EAP 7.1 is supported with Java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

change your drivername from h2 to db2jcc

db2jcc

it is picking up the h2 driver

and then change the default datasource to your jndi name in data-binding